# Software for streaming with DJI Osmo Pocket

Tags: gratis, video, streaming

I have a DJI Osmo Pocket camera and I'm trying to use it for live streaming.

It seems technically possible, since there is a software called [CosmoStreamer](http://cosmostreamer.com/products/pocketosmo/), which is capable of doing it. Unfortunately it needs additional hardware and a 150 US-$ license.

I am now looking for recommendations to make streaming possible at no additional software license cost, so I want [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) or [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source) software.

Since I have all kind of hardware around, you can recommend software for Linux, Windows and even Raspberry Pi. I really want to get it up and running just for testing purposes.

The solution should support Full HD video (1920x1080) at 30 fps. 4K is not needed. Higher frame rates are not needed.

I think that's enough for the moment. The request should be specific enough.